# How is the Reactor Context Accessible in the Controller

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, reactive-programming, project-reactor

If you populate the context in a WebFilter, how is it available in the controllers. To my knowledge, the context is available upstream at subscription time, but the WebFilters come before the controllers in the pipeline, so technically the controllers shouldn't have access to the context since it is downstream of the Filter in which the context was populated.
Any explanation and/ or references to useful documentation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This quote is taken straight off the reactor documentation:

> the Context is associated to the Subscriber and each operator accesses the Context by requesting it from its downstream Subscriber.

so what does this really mean. Well it means that when someone subscribes the context is created.

We then go into `assembly time` which means that each operator will then call upstream until it finds a `producer` that will produce data. When this is found data will start flowing, and each operator will access the context by asking for it from the operator after it.

That's why we declare the context at the end of the chain, because the operators ask for it downstream, to get sent upstream.

There is a very long and length explanation about how the context is propagated in the docs, and its too long to write as an answer here. But i suggest you read it and try out their examples.

So data flows downstream, context flows upstream.

[Context, reactor documentation](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#context)